# Approximating error using Taylors theorem

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation

I have used a Maclaurin series for the function $f(x) = \cos(2x)$

and have successfully produced:

## $\dfrac{2^n cos(\frac{n\pi}2)x^n}{n!}$

Now I want to estimate the error in approximating $\cos(2x)$ by $1-2x^2 + \frac23 x^4$ on the interval $[-\frac12,\frac12]$

How can I do this?

Comment: In first calculus courses, the remainder term is usually given in Lagrange form. Is that so in yours?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I believe so, but I am not certain as I may have done Lagrange(interpolation(?)) in another class, so I could be confusing that.

It is for a Analysis 1 course if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the **Lagrange** form of the remainder. This says that if we truncate at the term in $(x-a)^n$, then the error is exactly equal to 
$$\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1},$$
where $\xi=\xi_x$ is a number between $a$ and $x$.

In our case, we have $a=0$. It is useful to note that our degree $4$ polynomial is actually the sum of the terms up to $n=5$, since the term in $x^5$ is equal to $0$.

So we can take $n=5$. The sixth derivative at $\xi$ is $-2^6\cos(2\xi)$. It has absolute value $\le 2^6$. So as $x$ ranges over the interval $-1/2\le x\le 1/2$, we can say that the absolute value of $\frac{f^(6)(\xi)}{6!}x^6$ is $\le \frac{1}{6!}$.

**Remark:** If infinite series have already been covered, the estimate that the error has absolute value $\le \frac{1}{6!}$ over our interval follows from the fact that in this interval the Taylor series has terms that alternate in sign and decrease in absolute value. So the truncation error is less in absolute value than the absolute value of the first "neglected" term.

Comment: Is that character Ksi/Xi?

Very nice answer, I think I have seen something like this before, so I imagine this is what I am meant to go for. Very nice!

Comment: Yes, it is $xi$ (traditional). You might have been given the **integral** form of the remainder. In that case, a quick estimate of the appropriate integral will do it. Unfortunately, in these things the details of the background material one can use matter.

Comment: I believe I understand that remark, we are looking at a telescoping sum, and removing first and last term?(like in my newest question). I will look up the integral form now.

Comment: We are not looking at a telescoping sum. But in alternating series, gathering pairs of neighbours together gets us an estimate.

Comment: Why do we take $n=5$?

Comment: We **could** take $n=4$. That makes the calculation somewhat more complicated. The reason that we can take $n=5$ is, as mentioned in the post, that if we continue, the term in $x^5$ would be $0$, because the fifth derivative is $0$ at $0$. So the error if we truncate at the $x^4$ term is the same as the error if we truncate at the (missing) $x^5$ term.